# Постройте схему сложного предложения

Tags: синтаксис

Полковой командир , в ту самую минуту как он услыхал стрельбу и крик сзади , понял , что случилось что - нибудь ужасное с его полком , и мысль , что он , примерный , много лет служивший , ни в чем не виноватый офицер быть виновен перед начальством в оплошности или нераспорядительности так поразила его что в ту же ми ту забыв и непокорного кавалериста - полковника и свою генеральскую важность , а главное - совершенно забыв про опасность и чувство самосохранения , он ухватившись за луку седла и шпоря лошадь , поскакал к полк Тод градом обсыпавших , но счастливо миновавших его пуль . ( Л.Н. Толстой ) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]